# how to apply data template on listbox

Tags: xml, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I am having a data template,and trying to apply it on a list box,i have textbox,labels and a button on the template,but it isnt showing up on the listbox,i dont have any databinding yet but still it must show the textbox,labels,button but it isnt showing up,
here is the code for datatemplate it is used as a resource

```
<Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
                <Canvas Height="50" Width="850" Background="lightgray">
                    <Label   Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="150" Background="LightGray">
                    </Label>
                    <TextBox Height="30" Width="60" Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="370" Background="Black"></TextBox>
                    <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="10">$</Label>
                    <Button Click="deletebuttonclick" Canvas.Top="12" Height="10" Width="30" Canvas.Left="600" ></Button>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
```

and the code for my listbox

```
<TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
            <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
            </ListBox>
            <Label Canvas.Top="-18" Canvas.Left="185">Select Task</Label>
            <Label Canvas.Top="-18" Canvas.Left="377" RenderTransformOrigin="0.58,0.462">Enter Bill Rates</Label>
            <Button Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="575" Width="139">Click to add the task</Button>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
```

where am i going wrong?any helps,thanx

Comment: You have not set the ItemsSource of your listbox properly and hence list contains no item and so datatemplate is not applied.., set the ItemSource to the list of items

Comment: bt why isnt it displaying empty label and textbox.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DataTemplate**](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) is used to represent visual layout for listBoxItems. But, **ItemsSource collection is null or count is 0**, (assuming because you set it to just Binding) hence no items are generate and shown in your listBox. You need to **pass ItemsSource with some objects in it** so that DataTemplate gets applied to ListBoxItems.

For testing you can define ItemsSource in XAML itself:

```
<Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="EnumerableRange"
            xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
            xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
            ObjectType="{x:Type linq:Enumerable}" MethodName="Range">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
                <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EnumerableRange}}" 
             x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850"/>
     ......
</Canvas>
```

In the sample above i basically provide an integer collection with 10 items as ItemsSource. So, you will see 10 templates for it. In case you want to see more of the items, go and update the number from 10 to some other value in resource **`EnumerableRange`**.

Comment: what if i want it dynamic,means it depends on the xml file outside,which has certain amount of task,suppose there are 11 task.

Comment: For that you have to create collection in your code behind and set ItemsSource of listBox to that collection.

Comment: i am stuck on that beacause on my label ,i want the task to be displayed,please if you can help me out.

Comment: my location of xml storage is http://store.tymesheet.com/templates/Software-Developer.xml

Comment: Can you please open a separate question with what you want with this XML? Some snapshot would help. What you want it to be like. It's not intuitive from your comment that how this XML look like. Add more details to the separate question.

Comment: ok i can give you a whole scenario,i will add up a new question

Comment: Sure. Let me know when you add the question.

Comment: -i have posted my question